# How to show/hide an action for some rows in Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Sonata Admin. Is it possible to have an action that is only displayed for some of the rows, but not other rows, all in the same list view?

For example, suppose I have a User entity with an "active" field. I would like to show the "remove" action only for inactive users, not for active users. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can, in your **configureListFields** admin class action, when adding **_action** column on $listMapper, you should add template option for **delete** action, and then you can implement some logic in that template:

```
$listMapper
    ...
    ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
        'actions' => array(
            'delete' => array(
                'template' => 'YourAdminBundle:List:list_delete_action.html.twig',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

And then in list_delete_action.html.twig:

```
{% if admin.isGranted('DELETE', object) and admin.hasRoute('delete') and not object.isActive %}
<a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default delete_link" title="{{ 'action_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
    {{ 'action_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
</a>
{% endif %}
```

Here in this template you will have `object` defined, which is entity for each list row, so you can use its getters to get something from you entity. Note that condition in if statement `and not object.isActive`, so this is where you apply your additional if logic.